# how to correctly display the integral on the graph?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, graph, scipy

I counted the integral and I want to display it on the graph, but I wonder how it should be correctly placed on the graph. It seems to me that `plt.plot()` alone is not enough, or maybe I am wrong, I would like to know the correct way to display this result in a graph.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import quad


def integral(x, a, b):
    return a * np.log(x + b) 


a = 3
b = 2

I = quad(integral, 1, 5, args=(a, b))
print(I)

plt.plot()
plt.show()
```

Comment: you just wanna plot this single point?

Comment: also may be missing `I` in the `plt.plot()` ?

Comment: @Nk03 I just want to put the integral on the graph and I just don't know if it is enough to put the integral in the form of a logarymic graph, or if there are other functions to present the integral.

Comment: @JayPatel yes, I know that I is missing there, but I want to find out if it is enough to put the integral in the form of a logarithmic function (as in the code) or if there are other functions to rearrange the integrals.

Comment: There is no objectively correct way. It depends on the goals of the user. If you make a plot and explain in which ways you consider it to be incorrect perhaps we'll be able to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you know calculus but not so much about programming.
`matplotlib.plot` only plots data, so you have to construct an array with the datapoints you want to plot. Also the result of `quad` is a pair of numbers, the definite integral approximation and an estimated bound for the numerical errors.

If you want to plot the antiderivative of a function you will have to compute the integral for each of the points you want to display.

Here is an example in which I create an array and compute the integral between each element `a[i] < x < a[i+1]`, and use a cumulative sum to get the curve.

For reference I also plotted the analytic integral

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import quad


def integral(x, a, b):
    return a * np.log(x + b)


def II(a, b, x0, x1 = None):
    if x1 is None:
        # indefinite integral
        return a * ((x0 + b) * np.log(x0 + b) - x0)
    else:
        # definite integral
        return II(a,b, x1) - II(a,b, x0)
a = 3
b = 2
# plot 100 points equally spaced for 1 < x < 5
x = np.linspace(1, 5, 100)
# The first column of I is the value of the integral, the second is the accumulated error
# I[i,0] is the integral from x[0] to x[i+1].
I = np.cumsum([quad(integral, x[i], x[i+1], args=(a, b)) for i in range(len(x) - 1)], axis=0);

# Now you can plot I
plt.plot(x[1:], I[:,0])
plt.plot(x[1:], II(a, b, x[0], x[1:]), '--r')
plt.show()
```

[image: what you should see]

Also take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) if you didn't already, to know how to classify the answers you receive.

I hope this answers your question.